# Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API, Remote host closed connection during handshake

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to mysql which is on google cloud using below code. This is my first attempt to work on google cloud sql using mysql.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
String instanceConnectionName = "####";//providing correct connection name

String databaseName = "shan";

String username = "root";

String password = "####";//providing correct password


String jdbcUrl = String.format(
    "jdbc:mysql://google/%s?cloudSqlInstance=%s&"
        + "socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
    databaseName,
    instanceConnectionName);

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, password);
  try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
  ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SHOW TABLES");
  while (resultSet.next()) {
    System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
  }
}
```

}

When i try to execute this code, i am getting the below error:

```
    Feb 25, 2018 4:45:41 PM com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory connect
INFO: Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [stockinventary-1517746804001:asia-east1:shan].
Feb 25, 2018 4:45:41 PM com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory getInstance
INFO: First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2271)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.sf.si.poc.ListTables.main(ListTables.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to obtain credentials to communicate with the Cloud SQL API
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:549)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory.getInstance(SslSocketFactory.java:140)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory.connect(SocketFactory.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2192)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from location C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getCredentialUsingWellKnownFile(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:251)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredentialUnsynchronized(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:117)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.getDefaultCredential(DefaultCredentialProvider.java:91)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(GoogleCredential.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.SslSocketFactory$ApplicationDefaultCredentialFactory.create(SslSocketFactory.java:547)
    ... 18 more
```

I also ran gcloud sql instances describe  and it generated json file at: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json
Could you please guide me to figure out the actual cause of this issue and way to correct it?

Answer (score 5):

I got the answer with my own analysis and here it is:
I added GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable with json file(which was created when i run gcloud auth application-default login) as value.

This resolved my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: For me just running `gcloud auth application-default login` solved the problem.

Comment: @RoyShilkrot Thanks very much, this was the solution to the problem for me.